# completion Candidates for positional parameter in picocli

Tags: positional-parameter, picocli

I'm trying to provide completion for positional parameters.
Somewhere I found note that they are not very well supported, but currently I'm not able to find exact place in spec and I'm not sure what that really means.

In meantime I found CompletionCandidatesTest.java in sources which would suggest that they're supported in some fashion or at least prepared to support it.

That's why I would like to know if they work and if yes what I'm doing wrong.
Currently my code in Groovy looks like this:

```
package com.some.package


import picocli.CommandLine
import picocli.CommandLine.Command

@Command
class TjTest implements Runnable {

    static class TjTestCandidates implements Iterable<String> {
        @Override
        Iterator<String> iterator() {
            return Arrays.asList("aaaa", "bbbb", "cccc", "dddd", "eeeee", "ffff").iterator()
        }
    }

    @CommandLine.Option(names = "-x", completionCandidates = TjTestCandidates)
    String x;

    @CommandLine.Parameters(completionCandidates = TjTestCandidates)
    String param;


    @Override
    public void run() {
        println "Start"
        println x
        println param;
        println "Stop"
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CommandLine.run(new TjTest(), args);
    }

}
```

I performed required bash commands like this:

```
java -cp "picocli-3.9.5.jar;tj.jar" picocli.AutoComplete -f -n tjtest com.some.package.TjTest
. tjtest_completion
```

It works like a charm for an option. Unfortunately I was not able to make it work for parameter.
I was also trying to:

- remove @Option and leave only @Parameters
- put index in parameter

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. The current state (picocli 3.9.5) is that positional parameter completion works in [JLine](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/tree/master/picocli-shell-jline2), but not in bash/zsh.

There is an outstanding [todo item](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/issues/468) to fix this. Someone contributed a [pull request](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/pull/505) to address this but it had an issue and has not been merged.

Contributions are welcome!